# Is the Story Chess a bad fit for the site? If not, how can it be improved?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

As I type this, my [question about Story Time Chess](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/39459/does-story-time-chess-work-to-teach-young-players-the-game) has 3 close votes and 2 down votes.  I realize this question is different than many questions on Chess SE, but it's not clear to me that it is a misfit - there are questions about ChessBase, AimChess, etc. So, is the Story Time Chess question wrong for the site?

Also, a moderator commented that it should be made less opinion based. As I replied, I asked for studies (hoping someone might find one or more that I couldn't) or first hand experience with the aim of avoiding opinion based answers. I haven't thought of a way to re-word the question to conform with the request. What are ways to do this?

Disclaimer: I am not in any way affiliated with Story Time Chess. As stated in the OP, I am trying to evaluate whether to buy it for a young relative - for the money involved, I could also get a set & board and also a couple books.

Answer (score 3):

> there are questions about ChessBase, AimChess, etc

There are indeed and they are usually "product help desk" type questions to which I mildly object, because we are not the Chessbase help desk etc., but no longer vote to close now that I'm a mod.

However your question wasn't a "help desk" question. It was a "Is this product any good?" question. That is opinion based, whereas "How do I do this in X?" is fact based.

Comment: The wording in the question was "Is Story Time Chess effective?" which invites fact based answers.